# Need to reset database table every week

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a game which has a scoreboard based on weekly scores. At the end of the week I would like it to automatically delete all the entries and cache new values again. Issue is I don't know how to trigger such an even via PHP! Any help?

Comment: Which platform are you running your site on?

Comment: Unix... I guess, I am not sure of it... It changes on the whims and fancies of the system admin... So I was interested in something that would allow me to do it via www directory

Comment: like Col. Shrapnel said, why do you need to delete data? why not just select the scores from the past week?

Comment: That would do too... But emptying the table is my best option because, I have multiple tables. One to store golbal, one monthly, one weekly, I would not like to create mutiple copies for all users. The weekly contains top 100 players of the week only.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should set up a cron job.

Comment: I have heard of this, but is it possible via php? Or are they done in C?

Comment: write it in php, then say your crontab that it is executed with php

Answer (score 1):

Create a small php file which connects to mysql and TRUNCATES the table ( better and faster to truncate instead of delete all ).

And add this to your crontab.

```
0 0 * * 0   PATH_TO_PHP    myFile.php
```

Here is a crontab tutorial :
http://clickmojo.com/code/cron-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have unusual database design.
I know no site (gaming or not) that erases weekly data.

The purpose of database is to hold data. Why not to let it just do it's job?

Comment: Well I cache the data globally of all the players. The weekly and monthly are tabulated from the global for faster search for data to render it to the user as fast as possible. Hence I would like to wipe them clean. The main database remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Generally these type of activities are carried out using Cron Jobs or Task Schedulers which will run periodically to perform the action you would specify.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be creating a PHP script which deletes everything on the table, then creating a crontab job for it.